# API Call from advanced workflow

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Is it possible to make a call from advanced workflow to the Archer API?  I'd like to avoid making a custom object and didn't know if I could somehow otherwise initiate a call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't call Archer API from Advanced Workflow functionality.

Any data related manipulation can be done with a data feed. And where "Archer to Archer" data feed can't deliver "SQL" type data feed will. SQL data feeds targeting Archer Instance database can do magic if you are willing to document them and test them with every Archer upgrade.

I had to use Archer API only in very complex integration cases. In these cases API code was running on the application server as a service. I think that invoking API calls via JavaScript from end user's browser can be considered a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks.  We're using a data feed to populate items in security incidents but it is running every 4 mins (I believe this is best practice).  Unfortunately, while 4 minutes is quick it is not fast enough for our end user so I was wondering if there was another way to kick that off more quickly.

Comment: You can do it, but there are no simple and easy solutions there.
For example you can add a trigger object on the database side and monitor certain events like modification of the content table for specific module ID. This trigger can invoke .NET code located on the SQL server and from .NET code you can use Archer API.
I know at least one company who did this.

Note - a lot of custom development is required. Not sure if it is worth it, but you can try :)